# How to stop a thread created with dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nstimer

I want to forcibly stop the thread created by `dispatch_async` if its in use for too much time, for example pass over 5 minutes. By searching over the internet, I got some one thought there was no way to stop the thread, does any one know that?

In my imagine， I want to create a `NSTimer` to stop the thread when time specified passed.

```
+ (void)stopThread:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    forcibly stop the thread???
}

+ (void)runScript:(NSString *)scriptFilePath
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5*60 target:self selector:@selector(stopThread:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [LuaBridge runLuaFile:scriptFilePath];

    });
}
```

My runLuaScript method:

```
+ (void)runLuaFile:(NSString *)filePath
{

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    int error2 = luaL_dofile(L, [filePath fileSystemRepresentation]);
    if (error2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Dear @Martin R, should I use lstop like that, and when I want to stop the thread, just call `stopLuaRunning` method?

```
static lua_State *L = NULL;

+ (void)runLuaFile:(NSString *)filePath
{

    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    int error2 = luaL_dofile(L, [filePath fileSystemRepresentation]);
    if (error2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_close(L);
}

+ (void)stopLuaRunning:(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_sethook(L, NULL, 0, 0);
    luaL_error(L, "interrupted!");
}
```

Comment: Where does the `LuaBridge` class come from?

Comment: What I meant is: `LuaBridge` is not a standard Foundation class. Did *you* implement it or is it a 3rd party framework?

Comment: So the problem is that `runLuaFile` runs too long? You cannot kill a running block (or NSOperation). You have to implement `runLuaFile` in a way that it works asynchronously and can be cancelled.

Comment: Why are people down-voting? The attempted solution to the problem is not correct but I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @StephenDarlington: You are right, this turns out to be an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot kill a running block. You have to implement `runLuaFile` in a way that it works asynchronously and can be cancelled.

For example if running the script is done via `NSTask`, you can use `terminate` to kill
the task if it is running too long.

`NSOperation` will probably not help because `cancel` relies on the operation to be
"cooperative": the operation has to check regularly if it has been cancelled. That will not
stop the running `runLuaFile` method.

**UPDATE:** From inspecting the source code "lua.c" of the Lua interpreter, it seems to
me that you can cancel a running script using `lua_sethook`.

A very simple implementation (using a static variable for the Lua state) would be:

```
static lua_State *L = NULL;

+ (void)runLuaFile:(NSString *)filePath
{
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    int error2 = luaL_dofile(L, [filePath fileSystemRepresentation]);
    if (error2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_close(L);
    L = NULL;
}

static void lstop (lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar)
{
    lua_sethook(L, NULL, 0, 0);
    luaL_error(L, "interrupted!");
}

+ (void)stopLuaRunning
{
    if (L != NULL)
        lua_sethook(L, lstop, LUA_MASKCALL | LUA_MASKRET | LUA_MASKCOUNT, 1);
}
```

A more elegant solution would use store the Lua state in an instance variable of the class 
and make `runLuaFile` and `stopLuaRunning` instance methods instead of class methods.

Comment: The [LuaBridge runLuaFile] method will run a lua script, so it's difficult for me to check timeout and stop itself,because I can not control the logic in the lua script.

Comment: @Bob: But *how* is the script executed? Do you use `NSTask`? (Can you show your LuaBrigde implementation?)

Comment: I've added my implementation of runLuaScript method upstairs, please have a look.

Comment: I do not use NSTask, I use lua c library to interact between lua and c.

Comment: @Bob: I know a bit about Objective-C, but unfortunately almost nothing about Lua. If `luaL_dofile` (or `lua_pcall`) does not support a timeout or cancel method then this is going to be difficult. Perhaps you can ask in a Lua forum how this could be done.

Comment: Is the `cancel` method of `NSOperation` useless for this?

Comment: @Bob: I think so (see last part of my answer).

Comment: @Bob: I have now played a bit with Lua, and stopping a running script can actually be done, see updated answer. It worked in a small test app that I made. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: ,thank you very much for your help!I updated my code above, would have a look and give some advice?Now I'm trying to make a test,but can you share your test code?

Comment: @Bob: I have updated the answer. Note that this is only a simple implementation and works only if only one script is running at a time. I have also a better implementation using one `LuaBridge` instance per script and avoiding the static global variable. But that is on my home computer which I currently cannot access. So perhaps this helps as a starter, otherwise I can provide more information later.

Comment: @ Martin,thank you very much, that's much too helpful.I'll try it.

Comment: @Bob: That looks very similar to what I tried. Perhaps it depends on the Lua script? I just tested it with a loop that prints numbers from 1 to 100000 or so, and killing after 0.3 (?) seconds was successful.

Comment: Thank you martin, I made a mistake, The `luaBridge` variable in ScriptManager released when the ScriptManger dealloc, so when the thread called `stopPlaying`, the `stopPlaying` method can not ask `luaBridge` to execute `stopLuaRunning`, when I place the `luaBridge` at global env, thing got ok.Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` as they have built in support for cancellation so your operation can check if it's cancelled and your timer just calls `cancel` on the operation.

Comment: But that will not stop the `runLuaFile:` method if is is running too long.

Comment: @MartinR Why don't you add your solution ("You have to implement runLuaFile in a way that it works asynchronously and can be cancelled") as an answer? That's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

> By searching over the internet, I got some one though there was no way to stop the thread, does any one know that?

Don't bother; It's not yours to stop. If you have a reference to a queue, then you can call `dispatch_release` and it will be destroyed at the appropriate time, but you would not do this with the global queue.

Killing that thread would just kill a thread in the queue's pool and should be considered as good as undefined behavior.

If you want to control a thread's lifetime, create your own thread and interact with its run loop. But do ensure your programs return from their implementations normally -- don't just kill stuff because it isn't working for you or never returning. Martin R mentioned how this would happen -- your task should support timeout, cancellation, or another means to stop itself in the event the task has gone rogue.

Wain's also mentioned a good middle ground.

Comment: The [LuaBridge runLuaFile] method will run a lua script, so it's difficult for me to check timeout and stop itself, do you have any ideas?Thank you.

Comment: @Bob sorry, i don't know how your Lua implementation supports termination of a running script.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.

Here is a long, but helpful guide.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

The key point for you in this case, is there example of overriding main.

```
@interface MyLengthyOperation: NSOperation
@end

@implementation MyLengthyOperation
- (void)main {
    // a lengthy operation
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++) {

        // is this operation cancelled?
        if (self.isCancelled)
            break;

        NSLog(@"%f", sqrt(i));
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Notice the if (self.isCancelled) in the middle of the loop.

This is the "modern" iOS way of managing background operations without creating your own threads and managing them directly.

Comment: That has already been suggested in another answer, and I have the same comment: It will not stop the `runLuaFile:` method if it is running too long.

Comment: Gotcha... correct.  runLuaFile would need to broken down further to allow for an interrupt in operations.  Maybe the library doesn't allow for it.

Comment: I *assume* it can be done (see "Update" in my answer), but did not test it yet.