# dispatch_async handle event

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, dispatch

I know dispatch_async can handle thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
    // handle things that takes a long time
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
        // update UI 
    });  
});
```

But How can I cancel it the thread?

For example:

I have two viewcontrollers- AViewController and BViewController, A->present B, and a button to dismiss B.

I'll do `myMethod` in BViewController, the things is I want to dismiss B when exec `myMethod`, so I use `dispatch_async`, it did dismiss from B to A. but after going back to AViewController, here comes the audio.

How can I stop the `myMethod` after dismiss method exec immediately?

```
- (void)myMethod {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
        // handles thing A
        // play a audio
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
            // update UI 
        });  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop a thread created with dispatch\_async?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671828/how-to-stop-a-thread-created-with-dispatch-async)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need for this is not GCD and `dispatch_async`, but an `NSOperation`. It is a high-level wrapper around GCD that allows you to have references to your async operations, check their status, cancel them, etc.

I recommend using a very handy subclass named `NSBlockOperation`. You should keep a reference to your operation in your class, and if you need to cancel it, just call `[self.myOperation cancel]`.